# jQuery AJAX, GET, POST JSON issue, getting no response it seems

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: "http://domainsvault.com/test.json",
error: function(){alert('An unexpected Error occured while processing the resquest, reload the page to try again');},
timeout: 7200,
success: function()
{
    document.write('<div style="background:#FFF;color:#000;height:12px;padding:10px" id="info"></div>');
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item)
    {
        //document.write('<img src="'+item.image_url+'" border="0" onClick="alert(\''+item.description+'\')" /><br />');
        document.write('<img src="'+item.image_url+'" border="0" class="imginfo" rel="'+item.description+'" alt="'+item.name+'" />&nbsp;');
    });
}
```

});

the JSON http://domainsvault.com/test.json

```
{"items":[{"name":"hamburger","description":"A two-patty cheeseburger","image_url":"http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5734.png"},{"name":"hot dog","description":"A hot dog with mustard","image_url":"http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5735.png"},{"name":"pizza","description":"Pepperoni pizza","image_url":"http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5743.png"},{"name":"ice cream","description":"Soft-serve ice cream","image_url":"http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5739.png"},{"name":"fountain drink","description":"Ice cold drink","image_url":"http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5741.png"}]}
```

Far as I can tell the JSON is valid. The code is working if I hardcode the string it works fine for the $.each(). However attempting to get the JSON from the URI via post or get my response in Firebug is "200 OK" and shows it in red as if the File wasn't found.

Comment: Is your page running on that domain?

Comment: are you requesting from same domain, also from server response headers contain 'application/json'

Comment: That you're using `document.write` at all is worrisome. Avoid it at all costs, unless you ***really*** know what you're doing. You've got jQuery, so why wouldn't you just use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append)?

Comment: Ajax requests to third party websites are normally not possible because of security restrictions.

Comment: this should be the umpteenth cross domain policy request using $.ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the response you are getting.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/tnaWd/

Answer (score 0):

try using `jQuery.getJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
it can run cross domain